# How to Display nested JSON in angular 5+ ...?

Tags: json, angular, http, data-binding, nested

i am using a third party api. which provides a nested JSON object in return. In angular 7 i have used http get request to get data. The data looks good in console. But does not bind with the HTML.

I am using angular 7

```
ngOnInit(){
this._dataservice.getdata().subscribe(res => {
  this.cricdata = res;
  console.log(this.cricdata);
})
```

}

[This is the JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGchA.png)

Comment: Then it seems there is some issue in your template.

Comment: can you please tell us in html which key you want to display and it would be great if you provide us the JSON in text instead of image

Comment: what is a data type of cricdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want, but first, start to read the Angular Docs

```
<div>
{{cricdata | json}}
</div>

<div>
{{cricdata?.22374?.id}}
</div>

<div>
{{cricdata?.22374?.timeForNextDay}}
</div>
```

A better way is to convert your object response data into an array and then use a for loop to render the data.

An example

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  bucket: any[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(){

    this._dataservice.getdata().subscribe(res => {
      this.cricdata = res;
      console.log(this.cricdata);

      Object.entries(res.matches).map( res => {
        bucket.push(res[1])
      });
    });

  }

}
```

and then use a for loop

```
<div *ngFor="let item of bucket;">
  {{item?.id}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks George.. This works. but still i am geting an warning.. " Property 'matches' does not exist on type 'Icricdata[]' ". I have created an interface of Icricdata.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON data had been an Array we could have used the normal *ngFor syntax, something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let cric of cricdata">{{cric.id}}</div>
```

But it looks like your data is in the form of an object that again holds objects, so we are not dealing with Arrays here. Luckily Angular has a pipe for that called the KeyValuePipe. I believe this approach can help you along:

```
<div *ngFor="let cric of cricdata | keyvalue">{{cric.key}}:
  <div *ngFor="let subItem of cric.value | keyvalue">
    {{subItem.key}}: {{subItem.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Documentation for the KeyValuePipe: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe